# Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Issues happening only on Release build,

Tags: xamarin.android, .net-7.0

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   XAGJS7028   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat.dll'
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/DirectoryAssemblyResolver.cs:line 245
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve(TypeReference type) in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/cecil/Mono.Cecil/MetadataResolver.cs:line 111
at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve() in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/cecil/Mono.Cecil/TypeReference.cs:line 278
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.TypeDefinitionCache.Resolve(TypeReference typeReference) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/TypeDefinitionCache.cs:line 20
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.TypeDefinitionRocks.d__5.MoveNext() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/TypeDefinitionRocks.cs:line 40
at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.TypeDefinitionRocks.IsSubclassOf(TypeDefinition type, String typeName, IMetadataResolver resolver) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil/TypeDefinitionRocks.cs:line 94
at Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers.JavaTypeScanner.AddJavaTypes(List`1 javaTypes, TypeDefinition type) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers/Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers/JavaTypeScanner.cs:line 58 at Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers.JavaTypeScanner.GetJavaTypes(IEnumerable`1 assemblies, IAssemblyResolver resolver) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers/Java.Interop.Tools.JavaCallableWrappers/JavaTypeScanner.cs:line 48
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.Run(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.RunTask()
at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17 ReviewRev.Droid C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.68\tools\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets    1476

Issues happening only on Release build but debug build is working good

Comment: You can try to set the Linker Behavior of your app to `Don't Link` , and try again. For more information, please check [Linking on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker).